# Matlab: Integration dot-product

Tags: matlab, integral

Is it possible to integrate over a vector-product? For example:

```
integral(@(x) [x,1]*[x;1],0,1)
integral(@(x) dot([x;1],[x,1]),0,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how matlab calls your function. Internally something like fkt(0:.1:1) is called, which is not possible with your function. You can wrap your function into arrayfun to get the integral:

```
fkt=@(x) dot([x;1],[x,1])
afkt=@(a)arrayfun(fkt,a)
integral(afkt,0,1)
```

While fkt and afkt return the same for a scalar (e.g. `fkt(.3)` `afkt(.3)`) the function `afkt` can deal with vector inputs like `afkt(0:.1:1)` to get multiple values at once.